# matching members of one group against another or matching unordered mixtures

Tags: mysql

i need to match the members of a group against a list of other groups to see if there are any other groups that have the exact same members

Or in other words i want to match one mixture of a group against another and get back the names of matching mixtures.

example:

table A (this contains ingredients of my newly inventet goddmorningcoffee^^)

ingredientnames  have to be uniqe per mix and the order of ingredients inside each group
is random

`+-------+-------------------+--------------+
|uniqeid|mixname            |ingredientname|
+-------+-------------------+--------------+
|0      |goddmorningcoffee  |BEER          |
+-------+-------------------+--------------+
|1      |goddmorningcoffee  |PIPECLEANER   |
+-------+-------------------+--------------+
|2      |goddmorningcoffee  |BATTERYACID   |
+-------+-------------------+--------------+
|3      |goddmorningcoffee  |COFFEE        |
+-------+-------------------+--------------+`

now i want to match my "goddmorningcoffee" against table b
wich holds all the mixes ive ever stored.

table B has the exact same structure as table a .. just more data

`+-------+----------------+--------------+
|uniqeid|mixname         |ingredientname|
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|0      |heartcruscher   |SPEED         |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|1      |heartcruscher   |NITRO         |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|2      |metalcleaner    |PIPECLEANER   |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|3      |metalcleaner    |BATTERYACID   |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|4      |grandmas_best   |BEER          |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|5      |grandmas_best   |PIPECLEANER   |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|6      |grandmas_best   |BATTERYACID   |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|7      |grandmas_best   |COFFEE        |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|8      |grandpas_best   |BEER          |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|9      |grandpas_best   |PIPECLEANER   |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|10     |grandpas_best   |BATTERYACID   |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|11     |grandpas_best   |COFFEE        |
+-------+----------------+--------------+`

in this case i schould get back :

grandpas_best and grandmas_best

because they are the only
groups with exact same members in it.

sorry for the bad english i hope the problem is detailed enough.

p.s im after a 100% mysql solution not making use of anything else like php or something

greets^^

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is with `group_concat()`:

```
select mixname, group_concat(ingredientname order by ingredientname) as ingredients
from tableb
group by mixname
having ingredients = (select group_concat(ingredientname order by ingredientname)
                      from tablea
                     );
```

Comment: but what if i have list of new mixes instead of one and need a result like wich of the new matched the old ones "newmixname->matchedold , ..etc"?this would be alot more flexible

Comment: @user3774901 . . . Then you would have a question different from the one that you asked.